# What is sentence focus environment?

Tags: linguistic-typology, dialects, focus

I am currently reading a chapter about dialect that distinguish dialects according to the alignment that is used in the dialect (alignment such as nominative-accusative, tripartite. etc)

I am confused with this sentence

> In this pattern, S/A/P are left unmarked in the Sentence-Focus environment while overt marking for S/A (but not P) is obligatory when the subject (S/A) is focused.

What is the meaning of Sentence-Focus environment? thank you :)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_(linguistics) "In the sentence focus environment" then just means "in the part of the sentence where the focus of the sentence is".